# Apache CXF-based REST server in OSGI container

Tags: java, rest, cxf

I've been playing lately with REST services. I've created my service with Apache CXF and deploy it to OSGI container - which is Apache Servicemix 4.

I've managed to get it to work, but encountered a couple of caveats:

1. the first attempt to deploy the JaxRS server in Servicemix was to use bundle Activator. Despite the fact that the class of the Activator is being run, the server does not start. I suspect my configuration is wrong. These are the contents of Activator class:

   ```java
   public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
       System.out.println("TEST");
       Dictionary<String, String> restProps = new Hashtable<String, String>();

       restProps.put("service.exported.interfaces", "*");
       restProps.put("service.exported.configs", "org.apache.cxf.rs");
       restProps.put("service.exported.intents", "HTTP");
       restProps.put("org.apache.cxf.rs.provider", MessageWriterProvider.class.getName());
       restProps.put("org.apache.cxf.rs.address", "http://localhost:8080/");
       context.registerService(MyService.class.getName(), new MyServiceImpl(), restProps);
   }
   ```
2. The second problem was with REST annotations. I needed to add REST annotations both on MyServiceImpl and on MyService (interface).

Explanation for this - it was needed on  because:

- MyServiceImpl - becasue deployed project would not execute all methods - only the first one in the given class
- MyService - because I was unable to create a client instance for this WS

Actually I've seen in CXF tests that there is no interface-implementing class example. Generally annotations are put on simple POJO methods and Client class is declared programaticly, but this seems tedious and repetitive.

1. What's more, despite the fact, that the service is deployable and is working correctly my tests won't pass and I can't think of a reason for this. Perhaps someone could have a quick look.

I've put all the code on github: https://github.com/zygm0nt/cxf-playground in case anyone would be interested to look into this issues.

Please bear in mind, I haven't used CXF much before, so theses may be some simple problems, but searching google didn't give a definitive answers on them.